# Displaying HTML codes - &frac14; and &rdquo;

Tags: html, ajax

I am trying to display the real value of `&frac14;` and `&rdquo;`, but the browser is displaying it as ? (question mark) at a area where AJAX is enabled. While at a different browser locations it displays ¼”.

I want to display 1" but it getting displayed as 1â€.
Please advise.

Comment: Look at the source code of your page, maybe these are double escaped, like this : `&amp;_frac14;`

Comment: "Where AJAX is enabled" What does that even mean? AJAX can't be "enabled," let alone "enabled" in certain areas of the page. AJAX is a combination of technologies which are either enabled/supported or not.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you're doing something like fetching HTML from a second page and writing it to `innerHTML`.

Make sure that *all* your HTML is saved in the UTF-8 encoding. `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` will decode content from UTF-8, unless the response contains a `Content-Type: ...;charset=something-else` header. (A `<meta>` element is *not good enough* as `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't parse HTML to get the meta out; it has to be a proper HTTP header.)